# Override JQuery function with CSS in responsive design

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I ran into a little obstacle in my site. In the mobile version (<480px), I have a toggle button for comments. >480px version, the button is hidden, and I want to always show the comments. It is a responsive design so it is the same page when resized. How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#comments-container').addClass('mobile-hide');

   $('#show-comments').click(function()
   {
      $('#comments-container').filter(':not(:animated)').slideToggle();
   });
});
```

`.mobile-hide` is just `display: none;`. When I toggle the content to show then hide, and resize the browser to >480px, the content remains hidden. I've tried to set `.mobile-hide { display: block; }` for the >480px stylesheet, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using media queries in CSS to achieve this? It sounds like you don't need to use JS for this but I am a little unclear. For example:

```
#comment-button {display:block;}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #comment-button {display:none;}
}
```

To listen for browser width you can either set a tick event (happens every x seconds with setInterval) or use the resize event:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(ev) {
    if($(window).width() > 480)
        $('html').removeClass('mobile-device').addClass('desktop-device');
    else
        $('html').removeClass('desktop-device').addClass('mobile-device');
});

html.mobile-device .toggle-button {display:none;}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right now. It doesn't work because the CSS only loads once at the beginning, and the JQuery function will constantly toggle the div.

Comment: Cool, that was the event I was looking for. With some tweaking it should achieve the effect I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: No worries - I meant to make the css selector "html.mobile-device .toggle-button {display:none;}" -- good thing about putting the class on the body or html element is that all elements on the page can make use of it