# How to let @screen's display style work with jQuery's slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use @screen to change display:block or display:none for different screen sizes.
Everything works just fine until jQuery's slideToggle is called.

For example, initially the element is displayed. When I zoom in, the element will hide (by using display:none). However, in the zoomed in mode, when I click a button, I will call slideToggle to hide/show the element in the zoomed in state.

After the element is shown via slideToggle, when I zoom out, everything works fine, the element is still shown in zoomed out state.

However, after the element is shown and then hidden again using slideToggle (by pressing the button twice), after I zoom out, the element is gone (the @screen's display:block doesn't work) for all major browsers including IE/Firefox/Chrome/Edge/Safari. I have to refresh this page to make it show again.

Is there a way to reset the display state?

Thanks.

The minimal example code:

```
<header>
    <style type="text/css">
        #test {
            display:block;
        }
        #click{
            display:none;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
            #test {
                display:none;
            }
            #click {
                display:block;
            }
        }
      </style>
</header>
<body>
    <text id="test"> show with larger resolution! </text>
    <text id="click">click to toggle</text>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#click").click(function(){
            $("#test").slideToggle();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it possible to include a [working demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue?

Comment: Do either of these address the problem? [Override JQuery function with CSS in responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379523/override-jquery-function-with-css-in-responsive-design) or [Jquery .slideToggle() with CSS media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101797/jquery-slidetoggle-with-css-media-query).

Comment: @showdev Yes, it did solve the problem by calling hide or show on the corresponding element in windows size change event. Thanks.